# Mapping in Spark using Java

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a file name **myFile** in the following format:

```
1,A,2,B
1,A,3,C
2,B,4,D
```

I want to map the second indexed value of each line to the line itself:

```
A -> 1,A,2,B
A -> 1,A,3,C
B -> 2,B,4,D
```

How can I achieve this using Spark Java?

Comment: Reading about Spark basics sounds like a good start: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#transformations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I achieved it

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> pairs = myFile.mapToPair(s->new Tuple2<>(s.split(",")[1], s));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're reading a CSV. Spark natively supports those since Spark 2.x

Don't use SparkContext use a SparkSession

Just to print a dataframe, you want something like this

```
spark.csv("C:\\myFile").show()
```